# Probability of no matches in two shuffled decks?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A deck of 52 cards is laid out in a row. Then the second deck is laid out on top of the first one. Find the probability that none of the resulting pairs of cards will match.

I can't figure it out even for smaller sets of cards. Please, help me.

Comment: Look for 'derangements'

Comment: The fact that both decks are shuffled is a red herring. Assuming that all permutations are equiprobable, this is the same as the probability of matches with only one deck shuffled.

Comment: Google 'frustration solitaire'.